# Distinguish between single and Multi touch Android

Tags: android, android-studio, multi-touch, ontouch

I don't know if my question is valid or not for this forum. I do apologize in advance if that's not the case.

How to distinguish between single and multiple touch(with two fingers)?

What I want determine exactly is one button will be in corner of the screen.

Case A:
If user touches single touch and hold on this view, drag event should perform

Case B:
If user performs multiple touch that is holding the screen with two fingers with one finger on the button and the other on corner of the opposite side should launch different screen.

The below code I used to for holding on the screen for Case B.

Using the below code how to achieve Case A as well.

```
// touch listener which handles onLongPress(two points hold) and drag events
private View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int displayWidth = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        final int displayHeight = ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        // coordinates for drag listener
        float dX = 0;
        float dY = 0;

        // coordinates of first
        float firx = 0;
        float firy = 0;

        // coordinates of second
        float secx = 0;
        float secy = 0;

        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch->(Event : " + event.toString() + ")");



        // captures first touch in hold
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            firx = event.getX();
            firy = event.getY();
            dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
            dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
            Log.d(TAG, "1st cor:" + firx + ":" + firy);
        }

        // captures drag event
        if (event.getActionMasked() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            //handleAppSwap( Math.round(dX),Math.round(event.getRawX() + dX));
            Log.d(TAG, "Drag event happens" );
        }
        // captures second touch event in hold
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN && event.getActionIndex() == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "captures second ");
            secx = event.getX();
            secy = event.getY();
            Log.d(TAG, "2nd cor:" + secx + ":" + secy);
            mSecondFingerTimeDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        // release event  on screen corners
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP && event.getActionIndex() == 0) {
            if (((firx < X_OFFSET && firy < Y_OFFSET + 100) && (secx > displayWidth - X_OFFSET && secy > displayHeight - Y_OFFSET)) || ((secx < X_OFFSET && secy < Y_OFFSET) && (firx > displayWidth - X_OFFSET && firy > displayHeight - Y_OFFSET))) {
                if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - mSecondFingerTimeDown) >= 5000) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "HOLD AND RELEASE........");
                    mEngHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                    Message msg = mEngHandler.obtainMessage(ACTION_BOTTOM_RIGHT_RELEASE);
                    mEngHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Thanks in Advance. Any link or code will be helpful

Comment: Why not just read Google's Android Doc? https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have gone through this before putting up the question. docs mentioned event.getPointerCount() > 1 should be used.for multi touch events I tried with sample app even for multitouches for first time and last time it will go to single touch block in between multitouches code will get executed .